# Program type already present: org.kobjects.io.BoundInputStream

Tags: android, file-copying

When I move an eclipse project to android studio.
My way is copy file one by one and finally almost done, sync is ok, but run on phone the error just happen.

I also search for some like question, but not solve.
This is my first to ask, please be forgiving if you find anything offensive.

[image: The pic which error]

Comment: Do you have any files in `libs/`? What are they if so?

Comment: post your jar lib list.

Answer (score -1):

the error **Program type already present** means there exists duplicate package name in your project, press `ctrl + shift + f` to open **Find in path** dialog, and search `BoundInputStream`.

Then refactor(rename) duplicated package name.

Comment: I search by in project, module , directory or Scope are not thing show.